# Play audio from firefox extension's data directory

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm making a Firefox extension and I'm failing to play a sound that's located in add-on's `data` directory.

1. The first thing I've tried was playing it in a content script this way:

   ```
   var soundFile = self.options.soundFile;
   (new Audio(soundFile)).play();
   ```

   where `self.options.soundFile` is an option that refers to a resource file in `data` directory. But I meet security restrictions:

   ```
   Security Error: Content at http://example.com may not load or link to resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/stackoverflow-reiew-helper/data/complete.oga.
   ```
2. Then I've found a way to play sounds in `main.js` script (here: [How to play audio in an extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661507/how-to-play-audio-in-an-extension)):

   ```
   var data = require('sdk/self').data;

   exports.main = function() {
           var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
           var sound = Cc["@mozilla.org/sound;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsISound);
           sound.play(data.url('complete.oga'));
   };
   ```

   This one fails with the following exception:

   ```
   NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsISound.play]
   undefined 8
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm", line 140, in null
       aCallback(pipe.inputStream, aStatusCode, aRequest);
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/net/url.js", line 49, in null
       resolve(data);
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 143, in resolve
       while (pending.length) result.then.apply(result, pending.shift())
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 37, in then
       return { then: function then(resolve) { resolve(value) } }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 117, in resolved
       function resolved(value) { deferred.resolve(resolve(value)) }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 143, in resolve
       while (pending.length) result.then.apply(result, pending.shift())
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 37, in then
       return { then: function then(resolve) { resolve(value) } }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 117, in resolved
       function resolved(value) { deferred.resolve(resolve(value)) }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 143, in resolve
       while (pending.length) result.then.apply(result, pending.shift())
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 37, in then
       return { then: function then(resolve) { resolve(value) } }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 117, in resolved
       function resolved(value) { deferred.resolve(resolve(value)) }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 143, in resolve
       while (pending.length) result.then.apply(result, pending.shift())
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 37, in then
       return { then: function then(resolve) { resolve(value) } }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 117, in resolved
       function resolved(value) { deferred.resolve(resolve(value)) }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 143, in resolve
       while (pending.length) result.then.apply(result, pending.shift())
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 37, in then
       return { then: function then(resolve) { resolve(value) } }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 117, in resolved
       function resolved(value) { deferred.resolve(resolve(value)) }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 143, in resolve
       while (pending.length) result.then.apply(result, pending.shift())
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 123, in then
       else result.then(resolved, rejected)
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 37, in then
       return { then: function then(resolve) { resolve(value) } }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 117, in resolved
       function resolved(value) { deferred.resolve(resolve(value)) }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 55, in effort
       try { return f(options) }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 117, in resolved
       function resolved(value) { deferred.resolve(resolve(value)) }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 143, in resolve
       while (pending.length) result.then.apply(result, pending.shift())
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 37, in then
       return { then: function then(resolve) { resolve(value) } }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 117, in resolved
       function resolved(value) { deferred.resolve(resolve(value)) }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/core/promise.js", line 55, in effort
       try { return f(options) }
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/addon/runner.js", line 90, in onLocalizationReady
       run(options);
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/addon/runner.js", line 134, in run
       quit: exit
     File "resource://jid0-a02no8rrtu2pbize7g7sszzo0z8-at-jetpack/stackoverflow-reiew-helper/lib/main.js", line 8, in exports.main
       sound.play(data.url('complete.oga'));
   ```

   If I replace `sound.play(...)` with `sound.beep`, I get a nice default system sound. So, there should be something wrong with passing resource path to the function.

If it matters in any way, I'm using online Add-on Builder.

Please suggest a solution of playing a solution of playing extension audio resources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`nsISound.play()` takes an `nsIURI` instance, not a string. You have to create it via [`nsIIOService.newURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIIOService#newURI%28%29) first:

```js
var uri = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
            .getService(Ci.nsIIOService)
            .newURI(data.url('complete.oga'), null, null);
sound.play(uri);
```

I would recommend against this approach however, `nsISound.play()` API is [pretty much deprecated](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=683263) and IMHO not capable of playing ogg files anyway.

`Audio` constructor requires access to a proper HTML document. Easiest way to get one in an SDK-based extension is using [`page-worker` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-worker.html):

```js
require("page-worker").Page({
  contentScript: "new Audio('complete.oga').play()",
  contentURL: data.url("blank.html")
});
```

Both your sound file and `blank.html` (an empty HTML file) need to be located in the `data/` directory of the extension - note how the audio file is loaded via a relative URL. Right now I don't see a way to avoid having an empty HTML file in the extension, HTML files outside the extension don't have access to extension files and cannot play them.

Comment: The first solution works perfectly (after replacing ogg file with a wav). But the second one is passed silently with no errors in `Error Console` and no sound produced. What might be the reason for that or maybe how can I find it?

Comment: @Alexey: You are right, `<audio>` tags apparently don't play unless attached to a proper HTML document (and presumably its load group). So much for trying to be clever, `page-worker` it is then. I will update the answer later.

Comment: Very helpful answer. If I plan to play the same sound multiple times on various occasions in my program, is there a better way than creating a new `Page` each time?

Comment: @timgeb: The trivial content script here is merely an example, it doesn't have to be like that. You only need one page worker. Once it is created, you can send messages to its content script and tell it to play the audio file whenever you need it. See documentation on communicating with content scripts.