# firefox addon SDK not playing audio using new Audio

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a firefox extension, and I'd like it to play a notification sound when an event occurs. However, despite following the instructions from [Play audio from firefox extension's data directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449813/play-audio-from-firefox-extensions-data-directory), the sound doesn't play. It's stored in my data directory. Here is my code:

```
var pageworker = require ("sdk/page-worker");
let { setTimeout } = require("sdk/timers"); //setTimeout is not enabled by default in ff extensions

function playSound(sound){
  console.log("playing sound: "+sound);
  var soundPlayer = pageworker.Page({
    contentURL: data.url("blank.html"),
    contentScript: "new Audio('notification-1.mp3').play();console.log('the audio did run')",//This is where it should play, but it doesn't, even if I remove the console.log
    //The script does work if I type it into the javascript console, but replace the file name with a file:/// URL
  });
  setTimeout(function(){soundPlayer.destroy();},5000);//destroy the sound player after 5 seconds
}
```

but although both *console.log*'s are called, no audio ever plays.
This is both in the XPI and when using cfx.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Are both the html and mp3 files stored in the same folder in data? If so, maybe try with an absolute path: `"new Audio("+data.url("notification-1.mp3")+").play();"`

Comment: @willlma There were no errors in the console and using data.url didn't help unfortunately

Comment: Actually, that does seem to have worked (didn't the first time for some reason). Thanks! Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: Done. Not sure why it didn't work in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: How can I play audio from the web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, try using an absolute URL in the `contentScript` string:

```
"new Audio("+data.url("notification-1.mp3")+").play();"
```

Comment: This didn't work for me because the argument of `Audio` has to be a string (seemingly). Working solution: `"new Audio(\'"+data.url("notification-1.mp3")+"\').play();"`